# How to do parallel computing inside a cluster with the R future package?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, r-future

I would like to distribute jobs (with a `for` loop) inside nodes of a cluster (several machines). I try to use the R package `future` to do that. I didn't know if it's the best way to do that; I tried to use `foreach` of the `doParallel` package, but I didn't succeed. How can I figure out when the number of the loop iterations is greater than the number of cluster nodes?

```
library(doParallel);
library(doFuture);
#library(future);

registerDoFuture();

workers <- c(rep("129.20.25.61",1), rep("129.20.25.217",1));
cl <- makeClusterPSOCK(workers, revtunnel = TRUE, outfile = "", verbose = FALSE);

plan(cluster, workers = cl)

mu <- 1.0
sigma <- 2.0

for(i in 1:3){
 res %<-%{ rnorm(i, mean = mu, sd = sigma)}
 print(i);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the plain Future API, i.e. `future()` + `value()` or `%<-%`, there is no need to involve foreach, doFuture etc.  Here is how to use the Future API by itself and what output you can expect:

(A) Setup the workers

```
library("future")

workers <- c("129.20.25.61", "129.20.25.217")
cl <- makeClusterPSOCK(workers, revtunnel = TRUE, outfile = "")
### starting worker pid=20026 on localhost:11900 at 11:47:28.334
### starting worker pid=12291 on localhost:11901 at 11:47:37.172

print(cl)
### socket cluster with 2 nodes on hosts '129.20.25.61', '129.20.25.217'

plan(cluster, workers = cl)
```

(B) Explicit Future API

Here we create a list of futures explicitly using `future()` and retrieve for their values using `values()` (basically equal to calling `lapply(f, FUN = value)`).

```
mu <- 1.0
sigma <- 2.0

f <- list()
for (i in 1:3) {
  f[[i]] <- future({ rnorm(i, mean = mu, sd = sigma) })
}
v <- values(f)
str(v)
### List of 3
###  $ : num 3.25
###  $ : num [1:2] 3.24 3.29
###  $ : num [1:3] 1.251 2.299 0.923
```

(C) Implicit Future API

In this alternative, we create futures implicitly using the future assignment operator `%<-%` (which internally will do `future()` and then `value()` when you try to access the future's value).  Since `%<-%` can only assign to environments (and not lists, data.frames, etc), we need to use a container that is an environment.  Here I use the listenv class, which is an environment but allows you to index it as list.

```
library("listenv")  ## listenv()
mu <- 1.0
sigma <- 2.0

v <- listenv()
for (i in 1:3) {
  v[[i]] %<-% { rnorm(i, mean = mu, sd = sigma) }
}
v <- as.list(v)
str(v)
### List of 3
###  $ : num 1.15
###  $ : num [1:2] 2.2277 -0.0164
###  $ : num [1:3] -2.09 3.34 -1.09
```

(D) Use `future_lapply()`

If you prefer an `lapply()`-like approach, you could do:

```
v <- future_lapply(1:3, FUN = function(i) {
  rnorm(i, mean = mu, sd = sigma)
})
str(v)
### List of 3
###  $ : num 2.12
###  $ : num [1:2] 2.56 -1.21
###  $ : num [1:3] 2.89 -0.159 -0.983
```

(D) Using `foreach()`

If you'd like to use `foreach()`, then you can do as follows.  Note that it's best to always export global variables explicitly when using `foreach()` per design of foreach - however, if you *always* use `doFuture` it's actually not needed.

```
library("doFuture")
registerDoFuture()
workers <- c("129.20.25.61", "129.20.25.217")
cl <- makeClusterPSOCK(workers, revtunnel = TRUE, outfile = "")
plan(cluster, workers = cl)

v <- foreach(i = 1:3, .export = c("mu", "sigma")) %dopar% {
  rnorm(i, mean = mu, sd = sigma)
}
str(v)
### List of 3
###  $ : num 3.12
###  $ : num [1:2] -0.0887 -2.8016
###  $ : num [1:3] 2.15 3.5 -2.24
```

> How can I figure out when the number of the loop iterations is taller
>   than the number of cluster nodes?

I'm not sure what you're asking here.  Are you concerned about having more futures running at one time that you have workers?  If so, that is automatically taken care of.  If all workers are occupied, then the creation of additional futures will block until one of the workers are available again.

Comment: Thx! Exactely, I am concerned about having more futures running at one time that you have workers. I have an other question, inside if future I would like to save a txt file and send them inside a folder inside the master computer, is it possible to do that ?

Comment: There's no file-transfer protocol with futures, if that's what you're looking for. So, unless master and workers share the same file system, the only way to "communicate results back to the master" is via the value `v` of the future expression `expr` in `v %<-% expr`; much like how it works for regular expressions `v <- expr`.